# IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "Sock::Connection::Connection" matches the argument list C++

Tags: c++, winsock

I have this weird problem and I have no idea whats going on..  It won't let me create a class in VC++2012.  I get this error: IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "Sock::Connection::Connection" matches the argument list  C++

Here is my connection class in namespace Sock

```
class Connection
    {
    private:
        const char *host;
        const char *nick;
        LPHOSTENT hostEntry;
        SOCKET sock;
        unsigned short port;
        bool ip;    

        _onrecv onrecv;
        _onconnect onconnect;
    public:
        Connection(const char *_host, unsigned short _port, bool _ip, _onrecv myonrecv = NULL, _onconnect myonconnect = NULL);
        ~Connection();

        bool _connect(int delay_ms);
        int _isconnected(fd_set *rd, fd_set *wr, fd_set *ex);
        void start();       
    };
```

And here is how I'm trying to create it... but It wont work

```
#include "sock.h"

void WINAPI HandleConnection(SOCKET sock);
void WINAPI HandleReceive(SOCKET sock, char *buf, int len);

static const char host[] = "127.0.0.1";

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    if( Sock::Initiate() )
    {
        using namespace Sock;
        Connection conn(host, 9001);
    }

    return 0;
}

void WINAPI HandleConnection(SOCKET sock)
{

}

void WINAPI HandleReceive(SOCKET sock, char *buf, int len)
{
}
```

Comment: The bool _ip parameter (odd naming convention, imo) has no default value.  You only supplied two of the three required parameters.  You should also paste actual compiler errors instead of IntelliSense errors, as the latter may sometimes error on valid code (granted, not nearly as much as it used to).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like non optional argument `_ip` is missing when you invoke the constructor.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that.  Thank you, I haven't slept for nearly 32 hours.